# Get checksum (cityHash64) of first n rows of ClickHouse table

Tags: clickhouse

According to https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/hash-functions/,
I can get a checksum of entire table this way:

```
SELECT groupBitXor(cityHash64(*)) FROM table
```

What is the most accurate way to get a checksum of first N rows of a table?

As an example, I'm using a table with GenerateRandom engine as stated [here](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/engines/table-engines/special/generate/).

```
CREATE TABLE test (name String, value UInt32) ENGINE = GenerateRandom(1, 5, 3)
```

I tried using LIMIT clause, but with no luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using sub-query:

```sql
SELECT groupBitXor(cityHash64(*)) 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  LIMIT x)
```

---

```sql
SELECT groupBitXor(cityHash64(*))
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM system.numbers
    LIMIT 10
)

/*
┌─groupBitXor(cityHash64(number))─┐
│             9791317254842948406 │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```